# Bash regex overwrite line if multiple match

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a bash script where I have 3 regular expressions. I would like to, through conditional if, to find the match of the first pattern in the file.

If there is a match, then look for a match in the second pattern but only with the lines that have matched the first pattern.

Finally, to check the third pattern only with the lines that have matched the second pattern (which are also the ones that had already matched the first pattern).

I have the following code but I don't know how to tell that if there is a match to overwrite the "line" value to decrease the number of total lines to only the ones matching.

```
 #!/bin/bash
    pattern1= egrep '^([^,]*,){31}[1-9][0-9].*'
    pattern2= egrep '^([^,]*,){16}[0-1].[3-9].*'
    pattern3= egrep '^([^,]*,){32}[2-9][0-9].*'

while read line
    do
        if [[$line == $pattern1]];then
        newline == $pattern1
        if [[$newline == $pattern2 ]];then
        newline2 == $pattern2
        if [[$newline2 == $pattern3 ]]; then
        echo $pattern3

        fi
    done < mj1.csv  #this is the input file
```

I will call this script like `./b1.sh <filename>`.

Some input data:

```
EndYear,Rk,G,Date,Years,Days,Age,Tm,Home,Opp,Win,Diff,GS,MP,FG,FGA,FG_PCT,3P,3PA,3P_PCT,FT,FTA,FT_PCT,ORB,DRB,TRB,AST,STL,BLK,TOV,PF,PTS,GmSc
1985,1,1,10/26/1984,21,252,21.6899384,CHI,1,WSB,1,16,1,40,5,16,0.313,0,0,,6,7,0.857,1,5,6,7,2,4,5,2,16,12.5
1985,2,2,10/27/1984,21,253,21.69267625,CHI,0,MIL,0,-2,1,34,8,13,0.615,0,0,,5,5,1,3,2,5,5,2,1,3,4,21,19.4
1985,3,3,10/29/1984,21,255,21.69815195,CHI,1,MIL,1,6,1,34,13,24,0.542,0,0,,11,13,0.846,2,2,4,5,6,2,3,4,37,32.9
1985,4,4,10/30/1984,21,256,21.7008898,CHI,0,KCK,1,5,1,36,8,21,0.381,0,0,,9,9,1,2,2,4,5,3,1,6,5,25,14.7
1985,5,5,11/1/1984,21,258,21.7063655,CHI,0,DEN,0,-16,1,33,7,15,0.467,0,0,,3,4,0.75,3,2,5,5,1,1,2,4,17,13.2
1985,6,6,11/7/1984,21,264,21.72279261,CHI,0,DET,1,4,1,27,9,19,0.474,0,0,,7,9,0.778,1,3,4,3,3,1,5,5,25,14.9
1985,7,7,11/8/1984,21,265,21.72553046,CHI,0,NYK,1,15,1,33,15,22,0.682,0,0,,3,4,0.75,4,4,8,5,3,2,5,2,33,29.3
1985,8,8,11/10/1984,21,267,21.73100616,CHI,0,IND,1,2,1,42,9,22,0.409,0,0,,9,12,0.75,2,7,9,4,2,5,3,4,27,21.2
1985,9,9,11/13/1984,21,270,21.73921971,CHI,1,SAS,1,3,1,43,18,27,0.667,1,1,1,8,11,0.727,2,8,10,4,3,2,4,4,45,37.5
1985,10,10,11/15/1984,21,272,21.74469541,CHI,1,BOS,0,-20,1,33,12,24,0.5,0,1,0,3,3,1,0,2,2,2,2,1,1,4,27,17.1
1985,11,11,11/17/1984,21,274,21.75017112,CHI,1,PHI,0,-9,1,44,4,17,0.235,0,0,,8,8,1,0,5,5,7,5,2,4,5,16,12.5
1985,12,12,11/19/1984,21,276,21.75564682,CHI,1,IND,0,-17,1,39,11,26,0.423,0,3,0,12,16,0.75,2,3,5,2,2,1,3,3,34,20.8
1985,13,13,11/21/1984,21,278,21.76112252,CHI,0,MIL,0,-10,1,42,11,22,0.5,0,0,,13,14,0.929,4,9,13,2,2,2,6,3,35,26.7
1985,14,14,11/23/1984,21,280,21.76659822,CHI,0,SEA,1,19,1,30,9,13,0.692,0,0,,5,6,0.833,0,4,4,3,4,1,4,4,23,19.5
1985,15,15,11/24/1984,21,281,21.76933607,CHI,0,POR,0,-10,1,41,10,24,0.417,0,1,0,10,10,1,3,3,6,8,3,1,4,4,30,23.9
1985,16,16,11/27/1984,21,284,21.77754962,CHI,0,GSW,0,-6,1,24,6,10,0.6,0,0,,1,1,1,0,2,2,3,3,2,4,1,13,11.1
1985,17,17,11/29/1984,21,286,21.78302533,CHI,0,PHO,0,-5,1,30,9,17,0.529,1,1,1,3,4,0.75,1,2,3,2,2,0,2,5,22,14
1985,18,18,11/30/1984,21,287,21.78576318,CHI,0,LAC,1,4,1,37,9,15,0.6,0,0,,2,4,0.5,2,3,5,5,3,0,4,4,20,15.5
1985,19,19,12/2/1984,21,289,21.79123888,CHI,0,LAL,1,1,1,42,7,13,0.538,0,0,,6,8,0.75,2,0,2,3,1,1,4,3,20,12.9
1985,20,20,12/4/1984,21,291,21.79671458,CHI,1,NJN,1,15,1,35,7,13,0.538,0,0,,6,6,1,1,2,3,6,1,0,3,3,20,16
1985,21,21,12/7/1984,21,294,21.80492813,CHI,1,NYK,1,2,1,43,8,16,0.5,0,1,0,5,7,0.714,1,1,2,3,2,0,6,5,21,9.3
1985,22,22,12/8/1984,21,295,21.80766598,CHI,1,DAL,1,2,1,35,10,23,0.435,0,0,,0,0,,4,3,7,2,0,2,2,3,20,11.2
1985,23,23,12/11/1984,21,298,21.81587953,CHI,1,DET,0,-7,1,37,13,28,0.464,0,1,0,1,3,0.333,1,7,8,6,2,0,3,4,27,16.2
1985,24,24,12/12/1984,21,299,21.81861739,CHI,0,DET,0,-7,1,30,6,17,0.353,0,2,0,9,10,0.9,0,1,1,2,2,1,1,5,21,12.5
1985,25,25,12/14/1984,21,301,21.82409309,CHI,0,NJN,0,-2,1,44,12,25,0.48,0,0,,10,10,1,2,6,8,8,1,0,0,4,34,29.5
1985,26,26,12/15/1984,21,302,21.82683094,CHI,1,PHI,0,-12,1,27,7,16,0.438,0,0,,0,0,,1,1,2,2,1,0,1,2,14,7.2
1985,27,27,12/18/1984,21,305,21.83504449,CHI,1,HOU,0,-8,1,45,8,20,0.4,0,1,0,2,4,0.5,1,2,3,8,3,0,1,2,18,14.5
1985,28,28,12/20/1984,21,307,21.84052019,CHI,0,ATL,1,3,1,41,12,22,0.545,0,0,,10,16,0.625,4,4,8,7,5,1,7,5,34,26.6
```

To make things easier, pattern1 matches all rows where column PTS is higher than 10, pattern 2 matches the rows where column FG_PCT is higher than 0.3, and pattern 3 matches all rows where column GmSc is higher than 19.

Comment: Can you  add some sample data?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the lines?  It looks a lot like what you really want is `awk '$32 ~ /[1-9][0-9]/ && $17 ~ /[0-1].[3-0]/ && $33 ~ /[2-9][0-9]/` or similar.

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Hi @WilliamPursell, I would like to keep it as 3 different regular expressions, not merge them. It could be better to merge them, no discussion, but I would like to understand if it's possible.

Comment: @HatLess for sure, check the updated question :)

Comment: @WilliamPursell I'm trying just to filter out values from columns that don't match the patterns.  With bash if possible. If I have mixed awk and bash let me know please.

Comment: please update the question with more details about what you're trying to do; the subject says `'overwrite line'` while in a comment you mention `'filter out values'` ... these don't appear (to me) to be saying the same thing hence some confusion ... ? each of the 3x regexes appear to be targeting specific fields of input, so you may want to state what's supposed to happen if 1, 2 or 3 regexes match ... delete the row? keep the row? modify a field? it would probably also help if you update the question to show the expected output (corresponding to the provided input)

Comment: Hi @markp-fuso As I understand regular expressions, they help to find specific matches within a file. I'm trying instead of using only one expression, to divide the work into 3 steps. Each step find a match. If pattern 1 matches 1000 of 1500 rows, then pattern 2 can only find a pattern on the 1000 rows. If pattern 2 matches 400 rows, then pattern 3 can only find a match on the last 400 rows. I used the term overwrite to express the necesity to filter more and more the file, so that the resulting file has a lot less of rows than the original one.

Comment: would it be correct to say you only want to keep those rows that match **all 3 regexes**?

Comment: completely correct @markp-fuso But making use of "if" conditional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While an `awk` solution is going to be a bit faster ... we'll focus on a `bash` solution per OP's request.

First issue is regex matching uses the `=~` operator and not the `==` operator.

Second issue is that to keep a row if only all 3 regexes match means we want to *and* (`&&`) the results of all 3 regex matches.

Third issue addresses some basic syntax issues with OP's current code (eg, space after `[[` and before `]]`; improper assignments of regex patterns to the `pattern*` variables).

One `bash` idea:

```
pattern1='^([^,]*,){31}[1-9][0-9].*'
pattern2='^([^,]*,){16}[0-1].[3-9].*'
pattern3='^([^,]*,){32}[2-9][0-9].*'

head -1 mj1.csv > mj1.new.csv

while read -r line
do
    if [[ "${line}" =~ $pattern1 && "${line}" =~ $pattern2 && "${line}" =~ $pattern3 ]]
    then
        # do whatever with $line, eg:
        echo "${line}"
    fi
done < mj1.csv >> mj1.new.csv
```

This generates:

```
$ cat mj1.new.csv
EndYear,Rk,G,Date,Years,Days,Age,Tm,Home,Opp,Win,Diff,GS,MP,FG,FGA,FG_PCT,3P,3PA,3P_PCT,FT,FTA,FT_PCT,ORB,DRB,TRB,AST,STL,BLK,TOV,PF,PTS,GmSc
1985,3,3,10/29/1984,21,255,21.69815195,CHI,1,MIL,1,6,1,34,13,24,0.542,0,0,,11,13,0.846,2,2,4,5,6,2,3,4,37,32.9
1985,7,7,11/8/1984,21,265,21.72553046,CHI,0,NYK,1,15,1,33,15,22,0.682,0,0,,3,4,0.75,4,4,8,5,3,2,5,2,33,29.3
1985,8,8,11/10/1984,21,267,21.73100616,CHI,0,IND,1,2,1,42,9,22,0.409,0,0,,9,12,0.75,2,7,9,4,2,5,3,4,27,21.2
1985,9,9,11/13/1984,21,270,21.73921971,CHI,1,SAS,1,3,1,43,18,27,0.667,1,1,1,8,11,0.727,2,8,10,4,3,2,4,4,45,37.5
1985,12,12,11/19/1984,21,276,21.75564682,CHI,1,IND,0,-17,1,39,11,26,0.423,0,3,0,12,16,0.75,2,3,5,2,2,1,3,3,34,20.8
1985,13,13,11/21/1984,21,278,21.76112252,CHI,0,MIL,0,-10,1,42,11,22,0.5,0,0,,13,14,0.929,4,9,13,2,2,2,6,3,35,26.7
1985,15,15,11/24/1984,21,281,21.76933607,CHI,0,POR,0,-10,1,41,10,24,0.417,0,1,0,10,10,1,3,3,6,8,3,1,4,4,30,23.9
1985,25,25,12/14/1984,21,301,21.82409309,CHI,0,NJN,0,-2,1,44,12,25,0.48,0,0,,10,10,1,2,6,8,8,1,0,0,4,34,29.5
1985,28,28,12/20/1984,21,307,21.84052019,CHI,0,ATL,1,3,1,41,12,22,0.545,0,0,,10,16,0.625,4,4,8,7,5,1,7,5,34,26.6
```

**NOTE:** OP hasn't (yet) provided the expected output so at this point I have to assume OP's regexes are correct

Comment: Hi, as I understand it, you are getting the header from the original file but assigning it to the new file. And the same with the output right? you are reading the original file and generating a new file with the output.

Comment: correct, pull header (1st line) and put in new file, then have the `while` loop append any matching lines to end of this new file; at this point I'm just guessing what's supposed to be in the final results as we don't (yet) know the expected result of this exercise (eg, if you don't want the header data then you can remove the `head -1 mj1.cs > mj1.new.csv` line)

Comment: we could use `echo "${line}" >> mj1.new.csv` but this will require the script to open/close the file descriptor once for each line to be appended; by pushing the `>> mj1.new.csv` to the end of the `while` loop we only open/close the file descriptor once; either method 'works' but the proposed answer is going to be a bit more performant

Comment: Yes, sorry for not having posted the expected output. Its a file with more than 1000 rows. While the pattern is right, if the syntax of your answer is correct, it should be ok.

Comment: we don't need to see the 1000 lines of expected output, what we want to see is the expected output for the sample set of data you've provided ... in my case the 29 lines of input have generated 10 lines of output; the question now becomes ... do these 10 lines of output match your expected output (for the 29 lines of input)

Comment: Sorry, you are absolutely right. I do not seem to have generated the new file. I cannot even read the file with cat. The script works just fine, it's only the new file thing

Comment: not sure I understand your latest comment; if you `rm mj1.new.csv` and then `head -1 mj1.csv > mj1.new.csv` ... is the new file created? what does `wc mj1.new.csv` and `ls -l mj1*csv` show?

Comment: If I do rm mj1.new.csv, it says I cannot delete it because it does not exist. If I do rm mj1.new.csv  head -1 mj1.csv > mj1.new.csv, it tells me that "1" it's not an option for rm

Comment: I have checked with ls and no file has been created on mu current directory or other.

Comment: `rm` and `head` are separate commands; if you run `touch mj1.n32.csv1; echo $?` and then `ls -l mj1*csv` ... is the file created? what does the `echo $?` output? is `mj1.csv` in the current directory, too? if you `touch mj1.csv` and then `ls -l mj1.csv` ... does it show the timestamp on `mj1.csv` has been updated (per the `touch` call)? does `df -k .` show `100%` under the `Use%` column? what happens if you try the `touch/head/ls/cat` operations in a different directory?

Comment: echo $? returns 0. ls -l prints a timestamp, yes, but not updated. df -k returns 99%. touch mj1.n32.csv1 creates a file but it's empty

Comment: at the moment I'm drawing a blank; somehow you were able to create the `mj1.csv` file but now you can't `touch` it (ie, timestamp is not changing) and you can't create `mj1.new.csv`? if the current filesystem is not full (`df -k .` does not show 100% under `Use%`), and you can't create the file under a different directory (and/or a different filesystem), I'd recommend asking a new question as this doesn't appear to have anything to do with the original question

Comment: I will try to free up some space, I think it could be the issue.